State of the art stabilizer decomposition quantum circuit simulators - Suggestions
I've programmed an algorithm which decomposes a quantum circuit $U$ (and given initial state $|s\rangle$) into a sum of $N$ stabilizer states $|\phi_i\rangle$:
$
\begin{equation}
U|s\rangle=|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^N |\phi_i\rangle
\end{equation}
$
(Note that the circuits mostly consist of Multi-Controlled-Toffoli-gates and T-gates.)
I would like to compare my $N$ with the number of terms other (state-of-the-art) algorithms have achieved. Additionally, I'd be interested in the runtime of those implementations.
I know that the Qiskit-Aer Simulator offers a "Extended Stabilizer Simulator", however it's not clear to me how I can extract the number of terms they obtained.
Any suggestions on which simulators I should test against (and then importantly, how can I obtain the number of terms (e.g. for the Qiskit simulator))?
